# Magento 2.3: How To Initialize Js....?

Tags: magento2, javascript, magento2.3, phtml, datatable.js

I'm new to Magento 2.3, I was trying to apply jQuery DataTable and it's done, after that, I want to add it's [Button Extention](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57xiK.png), for that i need to add two more js,so i initialize it, now i'm getting error in my console, Here is my code:

**`/EC/Downloads/view/adminhtml/requirejs-config.js`**

```
 var config = {
    map: {
   '*': {
       dataTables: 'EC_Downloads/js/datatables.min'
     }
   }
 };
```

**`/EC/Downloads/view/adminhtml/templates/test.phtml`**

```
<script>
require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui','dataTables'], function($){ 
    $(document).ready(function($){
        $('#example').DataTable({
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
            'print'
        ]
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

**Initializing other two js `button.js`, `button_print.js` like this:**

These `Js` files are located in:

*/EC/Downloads/view/adminhtml/web/js/buttons.js*

*/EC/Downloads/view/adminhtml/web/js/buttons_print.js*

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "EC_Downloads/js/buttons":{},
            "EC_Downloads/js/buttons_print":{}
        }
    }        
</script>
```

**`Getting This Error:`**
[image]

Comment: Did you run setup:static-content:deploy command ?

Comment: yes run `deploy`, `compile`,`rm rf`,`c:c`,`c:f`